# Electrical in basement bathroom?

Tags: electrical

I followed this diagram to wire up my exact same situation. Now? Two of the three switches don’t work. One switch works - but now it powers half of my basement. On? Half the basements is on. Off? Half the basements off.

I have four wires going into a 3 bucket gang box. One is 14-3 (red, Black, white, ground) that is going to the fan/light combo and the other 3 are 14-2  (black, white, ground).

I am trying to power the following:
-1 light for the vanity (14-2 w/ normal switch)
-1 light for the shower (14-2 w/ normal switch)
-1 fan/light combo (14-3 going to this on a three way switch)

Any ideas what the heck happened?

[Wiring for 3 switch in a 3 gang box (1 switch is a switch with fan speed control)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/137302/wiring-for-3-switch-in-a-3-gang-box-1-switch-is-a-switch-with-fan-speed-control)

[image]

Comment: Please post pictures of the inside of your box showing the various cables going to the switches. I suspect that somewhere in the mix with the switches you have a cable that goes to "1/2 the basement" instead of (or in addition to) the cable that is going to the panel. For a setup like this, you really (not necessarily code, but definitely practical) should have all the new lights & fan on one circuit, *separate* from any circuits that are used for the rest of the house.

Comment: Did you install wiring to all 3 lights new yourself recently?  Or were they existing before?  Was the fan/light a separately switched fan/light before, or was it only a fan (alternately a fan/light switched together)?  I am examining whether you have really identified the supply cable correctly.  It sounds like maybe you did not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am just stating the obvious, but the diagram you have posted is correct. If you followed the diagram wiring scheme, then everything in your basement bathroom is working correctly.

This means that even though you tried to follow the diagram you have wired something incorrectly. You need to verify every conductor in you circuit and follow them through to find your error. You can safely do this with the power off and a continuity tester. It might help to have someone assist you. So check each wire and its path and location. I am guessing that somehow you have installed the power source conductor on the wrong post or posts. You can verify your source conductor with a voltmeter or non contact indicator.

One other thing that bothers me:

> 1 fan/light combo (14-3 going to this on a three way switch)

You named the fan/light combo correctly, then called it a three way switch. A three way switch is not a fan/light combo. A fan /light combo is a single device that has dual single pole switching actions. One for the light and one for the switch. Just make sure you have the right device.

Good luck and stay safe.